# How can I extract just the hour of a timestamp using standardSQL

Tags: google-bigquery, hour

How can I extract just the hour of a timestamp using standardSQL.

I've tried everything and no function works. The problem is that I have to extract the time from a column and this column is in the following format:2018-07-09T02:40:23.652Z

If I just put the date, it works, but if I put the column it gives the error below:

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "searchIntention" at [4:32]
```

Follow the query below:

```
#standardSQL
select TOTAL, dia, hora FROM 
(SELECT cast(replace(replace(searchIntention.createdDate,'T',' '),'Z','')as 
DateTime) AS DIA, 
FORMAT_DATETIME("%k", DATETIME searchIntention.createdDate) as HORA,
count(searchintention.id) as Total
from `searchs.searchs2016626`
GROUP BY DIA)
```

Please, help me. :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> How can I extract just the hour of a **timestamp** using standardSQL?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use [`EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract_1)(HOUR FROM yourTimeStampColumn)

for example:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

or

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-07-09T02:40:23.652Z')
```

or

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP('2018-07-09T02:40:23.652Z'))
```

Comment: That is incorrect. it DOES exist in BigQuery Standard SQL! Please try!

Comment: you might using EXTRACT against DATE type  - of course in this case HOUR would not be available - but if you use it against TIMESTAMP - it allows using HOUR ! so make sure you use timestamp and not date

Comment: It Works!! Thanksssssssss. :D

Comment: sure, consider voting up answer if it was helpful - which looks like it was :o)

Comment: what if I need an hour to second from current_timestamp

Answer (score 5):

In BigQuery Standard SQL, you can use the [`EXTRACT` timestamp function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract_1) in order to return an `INT64` value corresponding to the part of the timestamp that you want to retrieve, like.

The available parts includes a full list that you can check in the documentation page linked, but in your use case you can directly refer to the `HOUR` operator in order to retrieve the `INT64` representation of the *hour* value in a field of [`TIMESTAMP` type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type).

```
#standardSQL
# Create a table
WITH table AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP("2018-07-09T02:40:23.652Z") time
  )
# Extract values from a Timestamp expression
SELECT
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM time) as day,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM time) as month,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time) as year,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time) AS hour,
  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time) as minute,
  EXTRACT(SECOND from time) as second
FROM
  table
```